# How do I expand my current css responsive drop down navigation menu? Drop down is not working as expected

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Currently, I have a drop down menu which works this way:

http://www.feimediasolutions.com/NRA_Website/index_test_menu.html

When you begin to resize the browser to a smartphone and/or iPad view, I only want the drop down sub menu to "push" the rest of the menu items down after expanding. Currently, the sub drop down items only appear on top of the rest of the menu items.

How do I expand the drop down menu effectively in this case? Please help, will appreciate it so much and many thanks in advance!!

Comment: The accepted answer you have choosen solves your problem of pushing the rest of the menu down, but the whole concept does not work well on small screen devices. Firstly because your menu will cover approximately the whole viewport, so users always have to scroll to the main content. Secondly if one uses a mouse as input device this kind of vertical hover menu is "problematic". I would recommend a Javascript driven so called "accordion menu" in this case. Or you think about the several options to have all menu items visible and push the menu off-screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #colorNav li ul{
    position: relative;
    list-style:none;
    text-align:center;
    /*width:180px;*/
    width: 100%;
    left: -40px;
    top: 45px;
    /*left:50%;
    margin-left:-90px;
    top:70px;*/
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    max-height:0px;
    overflow:hidden;

    -webkit-transition:max-height 0.4s linear;
    -moz-transition:max-height 0.4s linear;
    transition:max-height 0.4s linear;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi the drop down u want to achieve is called responsive layout..Search regarding that u find tons of info regarding to do it...all the links below will help ur cause..http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/responsive-website-tutorial/                          http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-in-3-steps                                http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/responsive-web-tutorials/

Comment: ok I know that, however, I only need to push the menu items down after expanding the drop down. How do I edit my css code in this case?

Comment: Hi wat u have to do is to write media queries as in this post once the window size is decreased that defined css would take effect..              http://css-tricks.com/responsive-menu-concepts/

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is that the  tag holding the drop-down menu is absolutely positioned, removing it from the document flow. This means it won't affect the positions of other elements on the page. You should use:

```
#colorNav li ul {
  position: relative;
}
```

...on the full-width responsive version if you want the drop down to 'push' other content on the page. It'll need various other CSS fixups to make it look nice.

However, you'll have more issues, as there is no 'hover' on a touch device, so you'll need to trigger the drop down another way.

Comment: "... as there is no 'hover' on a touch device" that's not fully true. On Android devices :hover styles are applied on tap. But if the element with the :hover style is a link (an `a` element with a href attribute) the style is applied but also the link is executed. So it must be a `span` element or an `a` element without a href attribute. And for iOS devices you need a Javascript solution and e.g. a CSS fallback based on :target pseudo-class anyway.

Comment: @Netsurfer true, however I'd suggest it's best to apply a method that will work for most platforms first, rather than starting with a responsive layout relying on :hover styles that generally don't work well, then piecing together fixes for all the variations.

Comment: What do you understand by "for most platforms"? The only platform this method does not work well on is iOS. And the "work-around" is relatively easy. Which method is your favorit one?

Comment: @Netsurfer Well from scratch I'd structure the responsive nav to avoid having any elements that toggle a drop down being a link in themselves. I don't think it's intuitive on a touch interface. It really depends on whether the element is meant to be a link or just a drop down toggle, but if it had to be both, I'd generally prefer to go with a JavaScript double click option so I had one single method working on all mobile devices.

Comment: " the element is meant to be a link or just a drop down toggle, but if it had to be both" the latter is what I try to avoid at all costs, for having the option of a CSS fallback in case JS is disabled/ not available. ;-)